# MySQL over 100000000 rows always crash with page corrupt

Tags: mysql

Everyone:
   My English is not well,I want some help with my problem.

Environment: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
                mysqld  Ver 5.7.19  or 5.7.16
                FileSystem: xfs

I insert data into table , when table row over 100000000 ,mysqld crash with page corrupt.

Error log bellow:

```
10:23:15 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

    key_buffer_size=33554432
    read_buffer_size=4194304
    max_used_connections=4
    max_threads=600
    thread_count=4
    connection_count=2

It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 3727174 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f8f5c0ec8e0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f8fa8086ea8 thread_stack 0x80000
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0xf45e05]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x7cd464]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x7f90914fd100]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z20rec_get_offsets_funcPKhPK12dict_index_tPmmPP16mem_block_info_t+0x21)[0x10dc551]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x11001d8]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z23row_merge_build_indexesP5trx_tP12dict_table_tS2_bPP12dict_index_tPKmmP5TABLEPK8dtuple_tS7_mR13ib_sequence_tbP16ut_stage_alter_tPK16dict_add_v_col_tS9_+0x4bd)[0x1102f8d]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase19inplace_alter_tableEP5TABLEP18Alter_inplace_info+0x304)[0x10595f4]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xd7e50c]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z17mysql_alter_tableP3THDPKcS2_P24st_ha_create_informationP10TABLE_LISTP10Alter_info+0x39de)[0xd8242e]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0xef5)[0xd13d15]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3a5)[0xd18245]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0x11af)[0xd1945f]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x194)[0xd1a324]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x29c)[0xdea0fc]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x174)[0xfbdbf4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7f90914f5dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f908ffb221d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f8f5c0008f0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1014
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

when I use `innodb_force_recovery = 1` to recover the instance, I can run

```
select * from sbtest1 limit 100 ; 
select * from sbtest1 order by id desc limit 100;
```

but when I run `select count(1) from sbtest1 or select * from sbtest1` or mysqldump to dump data,the instance crash with error page corrupt.

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `login_log_1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `login_ip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `operation_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '6' COMMENT ' ',
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ',
  `status` int(10) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '：',
  `interface_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `interface_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `take_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `version_code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `remark` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `login_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `device_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_USERID` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_LOGIN_TIME` (`login_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4468000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COMMENT='loginlog'

 CREATE TABLE `sbtest1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `k` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` char(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pad` char(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 MAX_ROWS=1000000
```

Any one can help me ? Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

This link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_quoset_xfs.html  may help you eliminate xfs QUOTA limits as a possible cause.

max_threads = 600 appears to be many more than necessary to support max_used_connections of 4.

pfs_spawn_thread was one of the last items recorded in the error log.